# Python rawkit how read metadata values from RAW file?

Tags: python, metadata, photo, libraw

I'm writing python script and I need to obtain exif information from raw photo file (.CR2 for example).

I found Python [Rawkit](https://rawkit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) offer the ability to do that.

```
with Raw(filename=image_path) as raw:
  print raw.metadata

Metadata(aperture=-1.2095638073643314e+38, timestamp=4273602232L,
         shutter=-1.1962713245823862e+38, flash=True, 
         focal_length=-1.2228562901462766e+38, height=3753, 
         iso=-1.182978841800441e+38,
         make='Canon', model='EOS 5D Mark II', 
         orientation=0, width=5634)
```

But I'm a little bit confused, how read this values ?. For example I'm expecting **iso** value like **100/200/400** but what is **-1.182978841800441e+38** ?

My question is not specific for iso, it's also for shutter, aperture, ...

I ckecked [libraw](http://www.libraw.org/docs/API-datastruct-eng.html) and rawkit doc but was not able to find how read / convert this kind of values.

This part in the doc is not very detailed :

```
float iso_speed;
ISO sensitivity.

float shutter;
Shutter speed.
```

Can someone help me understand how to read these values?

Thanks

**[Update]**

As neo suggest, I will use ExifRead. In fact it's a better choice, I'm writting a python script. With ExifRead no need of extra C library dependency.

I was able to open Canon raw file and parse Exif but unfortunately facing a wrong value for the aperture :

```
EXIF ApertureValue (Ratio): 3
# My photo was taken in 2.8 (maybe a rounded value on this flag ?)
```

**Quick answer** : use Fnumber flag

```
EXIF FNumber (Ratio): 14/5 
14/5 is in fact 2.8 (do the math)
```

**Long answer** (how I found / debug that) :

Reading this exelent link Understanding What is stored in a Canon RAW `.CR2` file, How and Why ( http://lclevy.free.fr/cr2/ ) I decided to decode myself and know what is going on.

This link send me on the graal to decode a raw file [cr2_poster.pdf](https://github.com/lclevy/libcraw2/blob/master/docs/cr2_poster.pdf) 
From that I thought the best value seems to be in my canon specific MakerNote section on the FNumber value. (All values description is here [canon_tags](https://ExifTool.org/TagNames/Canon.html#CameraInfo5DmkII))

```
Tag Id : 3 (In fact 0x0003 that you write 0x3) 
Name : FNumber
```

I opened my file with an Hexa editor (hexedit) and ... I was totally lost.

Key things :

- An offset is a address in the file that will contain your value.
- Read : `C8 05` in the file should be read `05C8`. Example for an offset, the address is `0x5C8`

With that found the MakeNote section is easy.

Quick way is to search directly the `0x927c MarkerNote` (so in the file `7C 92`) flag that contain the address of the MakerNote section.
If you are not able to found that, go throught the `IFD` section to find the `EXIF subsection`. And then in that subsection you will find the MakerNote section

```
Tag     Type   Count        Value
7C 92   07 00  B8 A0 00 00  84 03 00 00
```

Offset : `84 03 00 00` -> `00 00 03 84` (`0x384` address)

Go to this address and search in the MakerNote section the `FNumber 0x3`

```
Tag     Type   Count        Value
03 00   03 00  04 00 00 00  C8 05  00 00
```

Go to the offset `0x5C8` to find our value (count 4 x type 3 ushort, 16 bits)

```
0x0x5C8 : 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00
```

And ... fail, in fact my canon does not filled this section.

Reading http://www.exiv2.org/tags.html The FNumber can be found in EXIF subsection.

Do the same process to find the EXIF subsection and the tag "`0x829d    Exif.Image.FNumber` type 5 Rational"
Rational type is composed of 64 bits (numerator and denominator ulongs) [Rational_data_type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_data_type)

```
Tag     Type   Count        Value
9D 82   05 00  01 00 00 00  34 03 00 00
```

And then read the `0x334` offset

```
1C 00 00 00  0A 00 00 00
```

As we can read in Hexa : `0x1C` / `0XA` 
In decimal, do the math : `28/10` = `14/5` = `2.8`

Verify I have this value in ExifRead

```
EXIF.py 100EOS5D/IMG_8813.CR2 -vv | grep -i 14/5
EXIF FNumber (Ratio): 14/5
```

And voila !

I was looking for `2.8` float and this value is stored in fraction format. So the library don't do the math and just simplify the fraction.

This is why we have `14/5` and not `2.8` as expected.

Comment: Have you tried to run 'raw-identify -v' from LibRaw? What was the output?

Comment: Seems to be good in that : (ISO speed: 400
Shutter: 1/50.0 sec
Aperture: f/2.8). I'm not a good cpp reader but I will check. Maybe a c -> python binding error

Comment: Probably, something like wrong data types?

Comment: What version of libraw and rawkit do you have installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suggest you use a library that is focused on EXIF reading. The stuff available in libraw/rawkit is really just a nice extra. I can recommend the [ExifRead](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ExifRead) library. It's pure Python and also damn fast. And it gives you better to understand values.

Comment: Didn't notice ExifRead was able to read raw. Seems good but unfortunately the value for aperture is wrong (3 instead of 2.8). I will try to decode myself with https://github.com/lclevy/libcraw2/blob/master/docs/cr2_poster.pdf to open a bug on ExifRead github

Comment: I suggest you try the ExifTool command line tool first and compare. It is supposed to be "the" reference.

Comment: I found my mistake and update my question, it's works with ExifReat thanks

Comment: Glad you solved the mystery, and good job in digging into the binary data with a hex editor!

Answer (score 1):

If compatibility with many formats is more of an issue to you than performance you could call exiftool as a subprocess with -j option to give you a json string which you can turn into a dictionary.

That should set you up for most raw formats and even stuff that isn't images at all. And it is going to squeeze every last bit of exif info out of the file. However in comparison with other options it is rather sluggish (like 200x slower):

```
from PIL import Image
import PIL.ExifTags
import subprocess
import json
import datetime
import exifread
filePath = "someImage.jpg"
filePath = "someRawImage.CR2"
filePath = "someMovie.mov"
filePath = "somePhotoshopImage.psd"


try:
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    img = Image.open(filePath)
    exif_0 = {
        PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
        for k, v in img.getexif().items()
        if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
        }
    end = datetime.datetime.now()

    print("Pillow time:")
    print(end-start)
    print(str(len(exif_0)), "tags retrieved")
    print (exif_0, "\n")
except:
    pass

try:
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    exif_1 = json.loads(subprocess.run(["/usr/local/bin/exiftool", "-j", filePath], stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.decode("utf-8"))
    end = datetime.datetime.now()

    print("subprocess time:")
    print(end-start)
    print(str(len(exif_1[0])), "tags retrieved")
    print(exif_1, "\n")
except:
    pass

try:
    start = datetime.datetime.now()
    f = open(filePath, "rb")
    exif_2 = exifread.process_file(f)
    end = datetime.datetime.now()

    print("Exifread time:")
    print(end-start)
    print(str(len(exif_2)), "tags retrieved")
    print(exif_2, "\n")
except:
    pass
```